# Planting yucca seed sprouts

Tags: seeds, planting, germination

I had some yucca seeds and I put them on a wet paper towel to germinate. In about a week they started to sprout, producing small white stalks as seen in this photo (not mine) [image: yucca_sprouts]

I then planted the sprouts in small pots, with the stalks pointing **down** - I assumed they will form the roots.
However, I then found this guide https://www.wikihow.com/Grow-Yucca that suggests pointing the stalks **up**. It has been about a week that my sprouts have been potted now. I dug one up and the stalk has grown considerably (it's about 3 times long as before potting), pointing straight down. So it doesn't look like it was placed in the wrong direction.

What is the correct orientation of the yucca stalks? Should I replant the sprouts or not?

Edit: my potted sprouts look like this:
[image: potted_sprouts]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They look fine. Roots will find its way down automatically via gravity, let nature take its course. The cotyledons (first leaves) will open soon. Nice that you have seeds from Yucca, most people use vegetative way of propagation.

Comment: Thanks, as you said, the first leaves have appeared now, so everything was fine.